# How to increase the idle timeout for zf2 zfc-user bjyauthorize

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser, idle-timer, bjyauthorize

I built an application using Zend Framework 2 (ZF2). I use zfc-user and bjyauthorize to handle the authentication for the application.

Everything works perfectly fine except the "idle timeout" is very short (possibly around 10 minutes). So if a user does not take any action on the web application for 10 minutes, then they must log back in.

My application does not require such tight security. I would like to increase this timeout to 4 hours. How do I do this?

Comment: Might be PHP's garbage collection settings, not zf2. [Look at these `php.ini` directives.](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) (Default `gc_maxlifetime` is 1440 sec = 24 mins.)

Comment: Rudie - thanks - let me check that out!

Answer (score 0):

Rudie was correct.

The idle timeout was not a feature of zfcuser or bjyauthorize. It was the garbage collection of php.

I changed the gc_maxlifetime directive in my apache2/php.ini file to 86400 seconds (1 day) and I no longer get automatically logged out after a few minutes.